# remove an element from array with structure of n-ary tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like below:

```
    var data= 
    [
    {"id":"root1","name":"root1","childNodes":
            [
            {"id":"child1_root1","name":"child1_root1","childNodes":
                [
                {"id":"child1of_child1_root1","name":"child1of_child1_root1"}
                ]
            },
            {"id":"child2_root1","name":"child2_root1","childNodes":[]}
            ]
    },

    {"id":"root2","name":"root2","childNodes":
        [
        {"id":"child1root2","name":"child1root2"}
        ]
    },

    {"id":"root3","name":"root3","childNodes":
        [
        {"id":"child1root3","name":"child1root3"}
        ]
    }
    ]
```

Now i want to remove a node with some id. If node has some **childnodes** they also should be removed from the array.

Suppose i have a array of id's of nodes to be removed:

`var nodestobe_removed=["child1_root1","child1root2"];`

In this first node has a child node, so node and its childnode both will be removed.

Second Node does not have a child node, so only this node will be removed.

Is there a simple way to do this in **JQuery** instead of looping through each node in the array?

Here is the [link to try](http://jsfiddle.net/Arvind_955/nffes/) . Use console to see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `inArray()` and `splice()` I suppose... if you're **that** keen to avoid looping:

`var data = data.splice(jQuery.inArray(nodestobe_removed[0], data), 1);`

This assumes you are certain that the values in `nodestobe_removed` are in `data`.

But really... looping is one of the well... main *features* of... like... programming and stuff.

You're code would be more flexible if you did something like:

```
//ECMAScript 5.1+

data.forEach(function(element, index, arr) {
    for(var key in element.keys())
    {
        if(jQuery.inArray(key, nodestobe_removed) != -1)
        { 
            data.splice(index, 1); 
        }
    }
});
```

This way, if the contents of your array change in the future you dont have to update your code.

Comment: I meant to minimize the loops as much possible.

Comment: You can't avoid the loops.
You need 2 loops to build this code.
If you think that the loops are heavy on your front-end code, then consider storing this huge array in a RDBMS database (MySQL etc.) or a NoSQL database (MongoDB etc.).
There's no place for a huge array on the front-end.

Comment: @user3594106 please accept my answer if it has helped you.